# How to update the value of file input field

Tags: angular

I need to change the value of avatar field to `this.imageUrl` because it is the response which is returned on successful image upload the image path in the server and after that in the `this.auth.updateUser(this.updateForm.value)` all the user details are sent which updates the user but the problem is that the avatar field has the value null
I tried this but it doesnt work `this.updateForm.controls.avatar.setValue(this.imageUrl);`
Gives the error `Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename`

Actual code

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   first_name: [this.userDetail.first_name],
   last_name: [this.userDetail.last_name],
   phone: [this.userDetail.phone],
   birth_date: [this.userDetail.birth_date],
   timezone: [this.userDetail.timezone],
   avatar: null
   })
}

onFileSelected(event) {
   this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
}

onSubmit() {
   this.submitted = true;  
   const fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('avatar', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
   this.auth.updateProfilePic(fd).subscribe((res: any)=>{
      this.imageUrl = res.data.file;
      console.log(this.imageUrl);
   },(err)=>{
      console.log(err);
   });


   this.auth.updateUser(this.updateForm.value).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
   },(err)=>{
      console.log(err);
   });
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="last_name" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="phone" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="birth_date" formControlName="birth_date" placeholder="Birth Date">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="timezone" formControlName="timezone" placeholder="timezone">
</div>
<div calss="form-group">
    <input (change)="onFileSelected($event)" type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" formControlName="avatar">
</div>
<button type="submit">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the user after the image is uploaded:

```
onSubmit() {
   this.submitted = true;
   const fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('avatar', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);

   this.auth.updateProfilePic(fd).subscribe((res: any)=>{

      this.imageUrl = res.data.file;
      console.log(this.imageUrl);

      this.auth.updateUser(this.updateForm.value).subscribe((res)=>{
         console.log(res);
      },(err)=>{
         console.log(err);
      });

   },(err)=>{
      console.log(err);
   });

}
```

Comment: inside `this.updateForm.value`  the value of avatar is still null, the real value is in `this.imageUrl`

Comment: where are you assigning imageUrl to avatar?